# Colocação pronominal e locução verbal "Devo calar-me, ou devo-me calar, ou devo me calar."

Tags: colocação-pronominal

No poema do Guimarães Rosa,

> Devo calar-me, ou devo-me calar, ou devo me calar [...]

o ultimo trecho “devo me calar” está correto de acordo com as regras de colocação pronominal com locução verbal?
Tenho essa duvida pois o poema é usado, sem explicação, como exemplo de Verbo auxiliar + infinitivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Devo me calar*** é corrente no português brasileiro informal e tem presença antiga na literatura; mas não é aceite na linguagem formal, nem ocorre no português europeu, formal ou informal, mesmo na presença de fatores que normalmente exigem a próclise.

O [InfoEscola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/) e o [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/colocacao-pronominal/) apresentam as regras de colocação prenominal na língua formal. Nomeadamente, nas locuções verbais com verbo principal no infinitivo, se não houver fator de próclise, o pronome vem em ênclise ao verbo auxiliar ou ao verbo principal:

> *devo-me calar* ou *devo calar-me*

Com fatores que com verbo único exigem a próclise (*não me calo, já me calo, e se te calasses? quem se cala*, etc.), o pronome vem em próclise ao verbo auxiliar ou continua em ênclise ao verbo principal; não ocorre nunca próclise ao verbo principal:

> *não me devo calar* ou *não devo calar-me*
>
> *quem se deve calar és tu* ou *quem deve calar-se és tu*
>
> *já te podes sentar* ou *já podes sentar-te*

A próclise ao verbo principal, com ou sem fator de próclise vem no entanto registada na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporânea* (Lisboa, 2014) de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra. Eles começam por explicar em pormenor (p. 397-9) as regras acima.  Depois (p. 400-1), continuam que no Brasil e em África, «principalmente no colóquio normal», ocorre também a colocação em próclise ao verbo principal (*devo me calar*) em qualquer tipo locução verbal (também com gerúndio e particípio). Citam a este propósito Martinz de Aguiar (*Notas de português de Filinto a Odorico*, 1955):

> «Numa frase como *ele vem-me ver*, geral em Portugal, literária no Brasil, o fator lógico deslocou o pronome *me* do verbo *vem*, para adjudicá-lo ao verbo *ver* […] Isto é: deixou a língua falada no Brasil de dizer *vem-me ver* (fator histórico por ser mera continuação do esquema geral português), para dizer *vem me-ver*, que também vigia na língua, ligando-se o pronome ao verbo que o rege (fator lógico). Esta colocação de tal maneira se estabilizou, que pouco se diz *vem ver-me* […]

Alguns exemplos da literatura brasileira (ênfase minha):

> Cada acontecimento, nesta guerra, **deve nos servir** de lição.
>   [(Pedro Corrêa Cabral, *Xambioá*, 1993.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-GItAAAAYAAJ&q=%22Cada%20acontecimento,%20nesta%20guerra,%20deve%20nos%20servir%20de%20li%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22Cada%20acontecimento,%20nesta%20guerra,%20deve%20nos%20servir%20de%20li%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-2oOtmffRAhUEVRQKHZd8BVEQ6AEIGzAA)
>
> Eu **devia te tirar** daqui a bofetadas.
>   [(Erico Veríssimo, *O Tempo e o Vento: Arquipélago*, 1961.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aeEQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Eu%20devia%20te%20tirar%20daqui%20a%20bofetadas%22&dq=%22Eu%20devia%20te%20tirar%20daqui%20a%20bofetadas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_orHUl_fRAhXI2BoKHdwrAscQ6AEILzAD)
>
> O velho **tinha me acompanhado**, mais devagar.
>   [(Rachel de Queiroz, *Dôra, Doralind*, 1975.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lIQtAAAAYAAJ&q=%22O%20velho%20tinha%20me%20acompanhado,%20mais%20devagar%22&dq=%22O%20velho%20tinha%20me%20acompanhado,%20mais%20devagar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinkOvHnffRAhUKPhQKHT7LC08Q6AEIKzAC)
>
> [...] e isto **está me incomodando** deveras.
>   [(Coelho Neto, *A Conquista*, [1ª edição de 1899] 1985.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=cW4VAQAAMAAJ&q=%22e%20isto%20est%C3%A1%20me%20incomodando%20deveras%22&dq=%22e%20isto%20est%C3%A1%20me%20incomodando%20deveras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihm-2In_fRAhUGQBoKHa6wCH4Q6AEILDAB)

Comment: Depois dessa vou comprar o livro do celso cunha hoje, essa duvida não me deixa em paz haha, gostei muito da sua explicação, pelo menos me confortou um pouco.
Oque eu ainda não consegui entender é a justificativa pra próclise  no verbo principal, no sentido do que é certo na "gramatica culta" e não no português falado 
"Depois (p. 400-1), continuam que no Brasil e em África é possível também a colocação em próclise ao verbo principal (devo me calar) em qualquer locução verbal."

Que justificativa ele da pra isso? Só um fator histórico?

Comment: Eu pensei que a colocação do pronome tinha algo a ver com o "ou" no inicio da frase(, ou devo me calar), tem alguma justificativa nesse raciocínio ou eu que tava tentando justificar o exemplo?
Eu tirei esse exemplo do cegalla...

Em um concurso publico,usando a explicação do celso cunha, estaria correto essa variação do " , ou devo me calar" ? 

Peço desculpas ae pelo monte de perguntas, sou novo no site...

Comment: @Luiggiab1, Não tem que ver com o *ou*; repara que nos exemplos que eu fui buscar a bons autores, não há nenhum *ou*.  A citação do Martiz de Aguiar é dá uma explicação. No Brasil, *vem-me ver* é mais literário, enquanto o mais comum é *vem me ver*.

Comment: @Luiggiab1 Em geral estas coisas não precisam de justificativa: o pessoal começa a falar duma maneira; e depois aquilo pega. A explicação do Martinz, é que logicamente o pronome é regido pelo verbo principal. Agora, porquê próclise e não ênclise? Possivelmente porque há no Brasil um tendência geral para a próclise (por exemplo *me dá um cigarro*, com *me* em início de frase, comum mas desaconselhado pelos puristas).

Comment: Então na norma culta brasileira é totalmente valido próclise no verbo principal mesmo sem "fator atrativo" digamos assim? (Estudo para concurso publico, sou formado em economia tambem, e ainda não tenho uma base muito boa no português pra poder distinguir esses detalhes, por isso o meu medo de errar...)
Agradeço mesmo pela explicação, a partir de hoje vou acompanhar as suas respostas aqui no site pra tentar entender mais haha

Comment: Para isso seria melhor a opinião dum brasileiro. O Cunha e Cintra dizem que é "principalmente no colóquio normal", e os examinadores por vezes são mais papistas que o Papa. Numa redação, à cautela podes sempre optar pela ênclise ao verbo auxiliar ou principal. Nota que nas locuções verbais é possível a ênclise ao verbo principal mesmo em condições em que não seria possível num verbo único: *não queria assustar-te* (mas obrigatóriamente *não te assustei*); não podes é dizer *não queria-te assustar*.

Comment: @Luiggiab1 Não, não é. A diferença é que a gramática normativa brasileira valida mais fatores de próclise que a europeia. Mas, na ausência deles, a ênclise é cobrada pelas bancas de concursos.

Comment: Mas então, nas locuções verbais, na norma europeia, não há nada que valide a próclise ao verbo principal. Vê exemplo dois comentários acima. Outro exemplo: posso dizer *não posso ajudar-te* (possível só em locução verbal) ou *não te posso ajudar*, mas não _*não posso te ajudar_ (nem _*não posso-te ajudar_).

Comment: Sim! Era esse meu entendimento, a regra se aplica ao verbo "escolhido" , digamos assim, a receber o pronome, por isso que eu fiquei com medo de considerar a próclise no principal quando esse não tem atrativo, como no caso de (, ou devo me calar) já que "calar" não é "digno" de próclise pois não tem atrativo, eu não escreveria dessa forma, iria preferir a ênclise... 

A duvida geral era se esse tipo de frase fosse apresentado em uma prova, como uma questão de certo/errado tals...
Nesse meio tempo já comprei o livro do Celso Cunha haha vou revisar tudo que você sugeriu, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @Luiggiab1 Alterei a resposta. Linkei dois sites que têm as regras da língua formal, que é a que precisas para o concurso. O que eu acho extraordinário é que algumas das frases dos meus exemplos estão até num português muito cuidado (a do Erico Veríssimo ou Coelho Neto), mas não seriam aceites nesses concurso por causa da próclise ao verbo principal!

Comment: Se for sobre pt-BR [Brasil Escola](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/a-colocacao-pronominal-nas-locucoes-verbais.htm)